# How to close current user Control and open new User control in WPF inside user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF application i have to develop app with user control, User control will work like pages 
I have open user control in MainWindow which will select language upon click and then close (current) language selection control and open another

**MainWindow Code**

```
<Window x:Class="WorkForceVisitor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkForceVisitor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Work Force Pro Visitor" Icon="Images/favicon.ico" Height="800" Width="1200">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/bg.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,1,5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.556,0.496" Height="754" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StackPanel Name="myStack"  Grid.Row="1" >
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
        private Header _Header;
        private Visitor _Visitor;
        private Control _currentUser;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Header = new Header();
            _LanguageSelection = new LanguageSelection();
            _Visitor = new Visitor();
            _currentUser = _LanguageSelection;
            myStack.Children.Add(_currentUser);
        }
```

user will click either arabic or english 
upon button click we will close **LanguageSelection** control
and open Visitor controll in StackPanel Name="myStack"
which is inside the mainWindow

**LanguageSelection**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WorkForceVisitor.LanguageSelection"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkForceVisitor"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Margin="10,0,1,5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.556,0.496" Height="754" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image  MouseDown="EnglishPress" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Margin="0,0,38,272" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="290" Source="Images/english.PNG">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/arabic.PNG"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
        <Image MouseDown="AranbicPress" Grid.Column="2" Height="200" Margin="50,0,0,272" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="Images/arabic.PNG" RenderTransformOrigin="0.511,0.527" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="285">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/english.PNG"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="100" Margin="0,0,440,517" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="294" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="Images/Logo.png"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**languageselection.cs**

```
static bool isEnglish = false;
        private void AranbicPress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // need to close current control and show visitor control in mainWindow 
        }

        private void EnglishPress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // need to close current control and show visitor control in mainWindow
            isEnglish = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a pro, but this should work:

**MainWindow.cs**

```
    public static Window Current;
    private Header _Header;
    private Visitor _Visitor;
    private Control _currentUser;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        Current = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        _Header = new Header();
        _LanguageSelection = new LanguageSelection();
        _Visitor = new Visitor();
        _currentUser = _LanguageSelection;
        myStack.Children.Add(_currentUser);
    }
```

**languageselection.cs**

```
static bool isEnglish = false;
        private void AranbicPress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow.Current.myStack.Children.Clear();               
            MainWindow.Current.myStack.Children.Add(MainWindow.Current._Visitor);

        }

        private void EnglishPress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow.Current.myStack.Children.Clear();               
            MainWindow.Current.myStack.Children.Add(MainWindow.Current._Visitor);
            isEnglish = true;
        }
```

However:

1) I don't think you need stackpanel inside of the grid for just one child;

2) I don't think you need to initialize your usercontrols before user needs them;

3) I would probably better create methods in the MainWindow to replace the controls.